# Can I add a style tag to innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, stylesheet, font-size, innerhtml

I'm trying to post an innerHTML table. Would like the font size in one cell to be bigger. Is it possible to include a style tag like so?

```
cell4.innerHTML = "<style: font-size:40px>" + "John Doe" + "</style>" +  "</br>";
```

I tried the following fiddle, but it isn't working. http://jsfiddle.net/s1dj3x8e/

Comment: @Billy It does not show any research effort; it is not useful

Comment: research? effort? didnt I try the style font-size and only missing the word 'div' from the the correct answer?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `<style>` tag is meant to be a container for CSS code inside the head, so what you're trying to accomplish cannot be done with that element in this context.

Try replacing the following line:

```
cell4.innerHTML = "<style: font-size:40px>" + "John Doe" + "</style>" +  "</br>";
```

With:

```
cell4.innerHTML = "<span style='font-size:40px'>John Doe</span>";
```

Updated fiddle (now with `span` instead of `div` as correctly pointed out by Zach below):

http://jsfiddle.net/jbhw1qf0/

Comment: You shouldn't use divs for styling a section of text. Also I'm curious why you have `" + "`

Comment: @ZachSaucier I picked up on that as soon as I got your comment. Was minimizing the original code and simply never saw the pointless concatenation.  Curious, what's wrong with divs being used to style a section? Span I typically would use inside, for example, a sentence to grab a word. But this context is the entire cell.

Comment: @DrewKennedy It's just syntactically incorrect for the same reasons why you'd use `span`s in a text section. That's what they're made for

Comment: @ZachSaucier Fair enough. You learn something new every day, even little things like this. I'll make the change in my answer.

Comment: @DrewKennedy So then it's the same answer as the one I suggested :P

Comment: But the meat of the answer is the same. Implementing the change suggested is easy to do and is not required in an answer

Comment: Style tags don't have to be in the head

Answer (score 4):

Style tags are meant to contain CSS blocks including selectors, allowing them to style multiple elements at a time. All of the CSS for the style tag should go between the `<style>` tags themselves.

To do what you're trying to do, you need to return an element that either uses a class that has defined styles or inline styles like so:

```
cell4.innerHTML = '<span style="font-size:40px">John Doe</span>';
```

OR

```
cell4.innerHTML = '<span class="fs40">John Doe</span>';
```

where  the CSS `.fs40 { font-size:40px; }` in your stylesheet.